# How to pass variable from producer to consumer in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am new to Kafka, working with scala, and I wonder how to pass variable from producer to consumer, I want to do something like that

In producer:

```
send(mystring)
```

In consumer:

```
get (mystring)
```

What is the best way to do this?

thx

Comment: Just to make it clear: Is `mystring` in message you want to "produce" (send to the broker) so that every consumer can read (a.k.a "consume") it. Or is it a variable you want to share between a specific producer and consumer?

Comment: I want to share it between specific producer and consumer

Comment: @Ahl Ahl: Producer and consumer are separate entity and runs in different JVM (Java environment, provided you are using java/scala client). So you can't share any message between.
Typically producer writes message to Kafka queue. And same message can be consumed by consumer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not a functionality of kafka. The idea of a distributed log like kafka is that you decouple producers from consumer. Everything you publish to the broker can be consumed by any consumer. If you need to share state between producer and consumer you have to find another way.

One idea would be to use zookeeper (which you have to facilitate anyways when you have a kafka cluster running). Maybe this small example from the offical zookeeper page give you an idea: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/javaExample.html